# Why is the probability of getting at least one 1 after 3 rolls of a three-sided dice not 1 - (2/3)**3?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, python

I've been told that the probability of getting at least one 1 after three rolls of a three-sided dice is $1 - (2/3)^3$. But if I try to do the math it doesn't seem true.

When I compute the probability of the event above, the sample space consists of the triples $(x, y, z)$ where the first component is the result of the first roll, the second component the result of the second roll and the third component the result of the third roll.

Now, how many of these triple exists? Maybe $10$ via $$3!/3! + 3 * 2 + 3$$ or using Python:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> list(combinations_with_replacement((1,2,3), r=3))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]
>>> len(list(combinations_with_replacement((1,2,3), r=3)))
10
```

Of them, I'm interested in the ones where 3 appears at least once. Again, I can compute that number via $$2!/2! + 2 + 2 + 1$$ or using Python:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda p: 3 in p, combinations_with_replacement((1,2,3), r=3)))
[(1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 3), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3), (3, 3, 3)]
>>> len(list(filter(lambda p: 3 in p, combinations_with_replacement((1,2,3), r=3))))
6
```

The number I get for the overall probability is $0.6$, while I would expect to get $$1 - (2/3)^3 \approx 0.70$$

Why is that? What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @lulu, sorry. I'm so confused I write the wrong title. What I wanted to compute is the probability of *getting* at least a 1 - not of not getting it. Also, the question is about why if I count the cases by hand I'm not getting the same answer people tell me to be correct.

Comment: No problem.  Post edit, your formula is correct.  To do it by hand:  there are $27$  equally probable rolls. If you exclude the $1$ there are $8$ possible rolls, hence there are $27-8=19$ possible rolls that have at least one $1$.  Thus the answer is $\frac {19}{27}=1-\left( \frac 23 \right)^3$.

Comment: Use `product` rather than `combinations_with_replacement` , i.e. `len(list(filter(lambda p: 3 in p, product((1,2,3), repeat=3))))` gives 19.

Comment: @ajcr OK. But why do I need to consider the order? I'd expect that if I'm using (multi?)sets, such that the order doesn't matter and I'm counting $(1,3,1)$ only once, and of them I'm considering only the fraction that satisfies the property of having at least a 1 among the values obtained - the computation I did in the OP -, I'd get the same result. Instead I get a lower probability.

Comment: $1 - (\frac{2}{3})^3$ is counting the probability that a 3 shows up on *any* of the three throws. There are $3^3$ ways of throwing this die three times and we consider (3, 1, 1) as different to (1, 1, 3) and (1, 3, 1). Using `combinations_with_replacement` means (1, 1, 3) is the only possible throw containing two 1s and one 3 (the 3 can only appear after lesser or equal die values, contrary to the formula). Apologies if I've misunderstood what you're asking in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not count the total number of number of possible *throws* using the three-sided die. Rather, it counts only the possible *values* in those throws (i.e. ignoring the order in which they are thrown).

For example, we would consider $(1, 1, 3)$, $(1, 3, 1)$ and $(3, 1, 1)$ as distinct possibilities when we roll the die three times. Your code says that these possibilities should count as one single throw.

As @lulu notes in the comment above, there are $3^3 = 27$ possible rolls of the three-sided die. The chance that a 3 is *never* thrown means $2^3$ possible throws. This means that there are $27 - 8 = 19$ possible throws where a 3 can appear. This is what the formula in the title of the question counts:

$$1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{19}{27} \approx 0.7$$

---

To emphasise why we care about order, here are the two situations phrased slightly differently:

1. Roll a *single* three-sided die three times. What is the probability that you see at least one 3 among these throws?
2. Hold *three* three-sided dice in your hand and throw them *together*. What is the probability that you see a 3 on the table?

In situation 1, we care about which die shows which value. In situation 2, we don't distinguish between the dice, we just look at the values . Situation 1 is answered by $1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3$. Your Python code and written working answers situation 2.

---

You can use `product` rather than `combinations_with_replacement` to generate the space of possible throws (as opposed to just the space of values that are possible with each throw). I'd probably write it like this in Python:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> possible_throws = list(product([1, 2, 3], repeat=3))
>>> len(possible_throws)
27
>>> sum(1 for throw in possible_throws if 3 in throw)
19
```

Comment: "Rather, it counts only the possible values in those throws (i.e. ignoring the order in which they are thrown)." Why that isn't valid? After all the original question was to find the probability that in 3 rolls I'm getting at least once a specific value. I should be able to ignore the order and consider the three rolls as a whole experiment. I understand that sample spaces are different, but shouldn't I expect to find similar probabilities?

Comment: I've tried to address this in an edit to my answer - let me know if it still doesn't explain things as you'd like.